# Libreoffice spreadsheet unable to reference columns by name

Tags: libreoffice

In Ubuntu 12.04, with Libreoffice Spreadsheet, I could name a column, say "PRICE" and then make formulas referencing cells by this name instead of the literal $letter$number format. This made formulas much more readable.

However, after I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, all my formulas that used this notation are now broken and showing "#REF!".

If I click the "Manage names" option under the column name dropdown, I see all my custom name mappings are still there, but I can't reference them anymore. How do I fix this?